# JavaScript с нуля

Tags: javascript, книги

Хочу разобраться с этим языком. Какие-нибудь статьи, книги, руководства посоветуйте :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Статьи - 
http://javascript.ru/doctree

Тамже есть закладка "Книги" (с отзывами и можно скачивать)

Answer (score 3):

Хорошая книга по JavaScript: Дэвид Флэнаган "JavaScript. Подробное руководство".

Answer (score 3):

Недавно на Хабре [запостили](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/javascript/117838/)

Answer (score 2):

Очень полезный [ресурс](http://www.w3schools.com/), не только по JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

https://hexlet.org/course/javascript/

Кроме того, настоятельно рекомендую прослушать этот курс, хоть он и не про JavaScript - https://hexlet.org/course/sicp/

Comment: А чем поможет в освоение JavaScript курс SICP?

Comment: А я и не говорил, что он поможет в освоении конкретно JavaScript. Но для общего развития он очень полезен. Узкий специалист подобен флюсу.

Comment: Хорошо, просто мне подумалось, что тут более глубокий смысл.

Answer (score -1):

Советую сразу изучать Jquery. Сведете к минимуму все проблемы с кросбраузерностью, отладкой и проч. проблемами.
По ней масса доков есть.
А сам JS достаточно понимать на начальном уровне.