# Совет по javascript

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте посоветуйте, с чего начать изучение javascript?

Comment: Какой опыт в веб-программировании уже имеется?

Comment: да есть html css

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В памяти чётко отложилось это изображение с такой подписью: *"Справа - все, что придумали в JavaScript. Слева — все полезное в JavaScript"*.
[image]

- Книга справа: **Д. Флэнаган - JavaScript. Подробное руководство**
- Книга слева: **Д. Крокфорд - JavaScript: сильные стороны**

Более подробного описания самого языка и его возможностей чем в книге Д. Флэнагана вам не найти. Это настольная книга для JavaScript-программистов, справочник, в котором можно найти ответ на любой вопрос касаемо языка и API, предоставляемых браузерами. На неё стоит обратить внимание, если вы всеръез решили освоить JavaScript.

Книга слева уже для более опытных. Из неё можно узнать где и когда лучше применять какие подходы, какие надежные конструкции использовать, чтобы не "прострелить себе ногу". Но не стоит её читать первой, не ознакомившись с правой книгой. Тем более, её русский перевод оставляет желать лучшего.

---

Кстати, похожие вопросы уже не один раз задавались здесь:

- [JavaScript - с чего начать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/224202/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-javascript-%D1%81-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)
- [C чего начать изучение JS?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/44594/javascript-c-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-js)
- [JavaScript с нуля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1842/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-javascript-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F)
- и еще вопросов 5-6.., не ленитесь - ищите

Для полноты картины приведу ответ на подобный вопрос со [StackOverflow: Best resources to learn JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246/best-resources-to-learn-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

1. [Хороший учебник](http://learn.javascript.ru) на русском по js, особенно если есть базовое представление о программировании и html с css. Если базовых представлений о программировании нет, то я не советовал бы начинать с js.
2. Html надо чуть-чуть представлять. Если представления нет, то [получить его](http://htmlbook.ru/)